# Java atomic classes in compound operations

Tags: java

Will the following code cause race condition issue if several threads invoke the "incrementCount" method?

```
public class sample {

       private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

       public int getCurrentCount {
          int current = counter.getAndIncrement();
          if (counter.compareAndSet(8, 0)) current = 0;
          return current;
      }
}
```

If it causes race condition, what are the possible solution other than using synchronized keyword?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want to let the counter exceed 8 and this won't work. There are race conditions.

It looks like you want a mod 8 counter. The easiest way is to leave the AtomicInteger alone and use something like

```
int current = counter.getAndIncrement() & 7;
```

(which is fixed and optimized version of `% 8`). For computations mod 8 or any other power of two it works perfectly, for other number you'd need `% N` and get problems with int overflowing to negative numbers.

The direct solution goes as follows

```
public int getCurrentCount {
    while (true) {
        int current = counter.get();
        int next = (current+1) % 8;
        if (counter.compareAndSet(current, next))) return next;
    }
}
```

This is about how `getAndIncrement()` itself works, just slightly modified.

Comment: +0: % 8 can return a negative number. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it probably does not do what you want (there is a kind of race condition).

1. One thread may call `getAndIncrement()` and receive a 8
2. A second thread may call `getAndIncrement()` and receive a 9
3. The first thread tries `compareAndSet` but the value is not 8
4. The second thread tries `compareAndSet` but the value is not 8

If there's no risk of overflowing, you could do something like

```
return counter.getAndIncrement() % 8;
```

Relying on that something does not overflow seems like a poor idea to me though, and I would probably do roughly what you do, but let the method be `synchronized`.

- Related question: [Modular increment with Java's Atomic classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810881/modular-increment-with-javas-atomic-classes)

Comment: +0: % 8 can return a negative number.

Comment: Using `counter.getAndIncrement() & 7;` works always and is much faster. Something like this is applicable to powers of two only.

Comment: Computing `x & 7` takes one cycle, computing `x % 8` takes dozens of them. Of course in the context of the whole program (or even in this context) it may be absolutely negligible. No hurry to optimize, but `&` simply behaves much better than `%`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code for getAndIncrement()

```
public int getCurrentCount() {
  for(;;) {
    int courrent = counter.get();
    int next = current + 1;
    if (next >= 8) next = 0;
    if (counter.compareAndSet(current, next))
      return current;
  }
}
```

However a simpler implementation in your case is to do

```
public int getCurrentCount() {
  return counter.getAndIncrement() & 0x7;
}
```

Comment: How does the first implementation cycle back to 0?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? Even if you use the fixes proposed by ajoobe or maartinus you can end up with different threads getting the same answer - consider 20 threads running simultaneously. I don't see any interesting significance of this "counter" as you present it here - you may as well just pick a random number between 0 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the what you want is to have a counter form 0 to 7.

If that is the case then a race condition can possibly happen and the value of counter can become 9.

Unless you are ok to use % soln. as said by others, you micht have to use synchronized.