# Specify binary digits length for Java AtomicInteger

Tags: java, atomicinteger

Java AtomicInteger is using the regular 4 bytes length of `int`.

If we run the following code

```
AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
System.out.println(i);
i.decrementAndGet();
System.out.println(i);
```

We will get

```
-2147483648
2147483647
```

Is there a way to set the size of the atomic integer, to make it 20 bits long instead of 32 bits and maintain the atomicity?

for example, the new result will be

```
-524288
524287
```

which is  `-2^19` and `2^19-1`

Comment: for what purpose do you need to restrict `AtomicInteger` to only 20 bits?

Comment: I would just write my own based on the code for `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: You could build something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/4811021/285976 using modulo 2^20.